# Cannot call method because of unsatisfied trait bounds

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement parts of the minecraft protocol (https://wiki.vg/).
I've successfully implemented a decoder to decode packets. But I'm stuck with the encoding part. The thing is that the minecraft protocol uses "minecraft varints" (https://wiki.vg/Protocol#VarInt_and_VarLong) and I want to have methods to write data as varints.

So my goal is to have a trait named `Encoder` with these methods:

```
    fn write_var_int(&mut self, value: i32) -> Result<(), error::EncodeError>;
    fn write_var_long(&mut self, value: i64) -> Result<(), error::EncodeError>;
    fn write_string(&mut self, value: &str) -> Result<(), error::EncodeError>;
```

At the moment, I've only written the code for the first method:

```
fn write_var_int(&mut self, mut value: i32) -> Result<(), error::EncodeError> {
loop {
            let mut byte = (value & 0b01111111) as u8;

            if byte == 0 {
                self.write_u8(byte).unwrap();
                break;
            }

            self.write_u8(byte | 0b10000000).unwrap();
            value = value >> 7;
        }
Ok(())
}
```

In `main.rs` I import the module `Encoder` and I try to use it on a cursor :

```
let test = [0; 17];
let mut wrt = Cursor::new(test);
wrt.write_var_int(packet.id);
```

But I get these compilation errors:

```
error[E0599]: the method `write_var_int` exists for struct `std::io::Cursor<[{integer}; 17]>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:57:37
   |
57 | ...                   wrt.write_var_int(packet.id);
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `std::io::Cursor<[{integer}; 17]>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
  ::: /home/clement/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/std/src/io/cursor.rs:75:1
   |
75 | pub struct Cursor<T> {
   | --------------------
   | |
   | doesn't satisfy `std::io::Cursor<[{integer}; 17]>: Encoder`
   | doesn't satisfy `std::io::Cursor<[{integer}; 17]>: std::io::Write`
   |
note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied because of the requirements of the implementation of `Encoder` for `_`:
      `std::io::Cursor<[{integer}; 17]>: std::io::Write`
  --> src/protocol/encoder.rs:12:16
   |
12 | impl<W: Write> Encoder for W {
   |                ^^^^^^^     ^

warning: unused import: `protocol::encoder::Encoder`
  --> src/main.rs:11:5
   |
11 | use protocol::encoder::Encoder;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
warning: `eupim` (bin "eupim") generated 2 warnings
error: could not compile `eupim` due to previous error; 2 warnings emitted
```

I don't understand why the import of the `Encoder` module is marked as unused, and how to fix these errors.

I'll be pleased to have hints on how to fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your reply @canton7, sorry i deleted your comment by mistake.

Then, I don't understand why I don't get this kind of error when I've implemented this trait:

```
pub trait Decoder {
    fn read_var_int(&mut self) -> Result<i32, error::DecodeError>;
    fn read_var_long(&mut self) -> Result<i64, error::DecodeError>;
    fn read_string(&mut self) -> Result<String, error::DecodeError>;
    fn read_u16_big_endian(&mut self) -> Result<u16, error::DecodeError>;
}
```
On `impl<R: Read> Decoder for R`

Comment: I tried to turn the code in your question into a [mcve], [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c87a05ed76b10774e260bf1ce8011332). The problem there is that `Write` is [only implemented for `Cursor<&mut [u8]>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html#impl-Write), and you've got a `Cursor<[i32; 17]>`. If we change the array to contain `u8`s, and change it to give a mutable reference to a slice of this array, [things compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d5ce09732b099d1c639a4f7d314de734)

Comment: OK I understand, I had already tried to force the type of the array to be u8 but without success. The key was the slice: `Cursor::new(&mut test[..]);`

Thank you so much!

So we need to pass a mutable reference to a slice of the array because of the &mut [u8] ?

Comment: Yes. `Write` is only implemented for a `Cursor<&mut [u8]>`, where the `&mut [u8]` is a mutable reference to a u8 slice.

Comment: OK thank you.
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to turn the code in your question into a minumal reproducible example:

```
use std::io::{Cursor, Write};
use std::slice;

mod error {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub enum EncodeError { }
}

trait Encoder {
    fn write_u8(&mut self, value: u8) -> Result<(), error::EncodeError>;
    fn write_var_int(&mut self, value: i32) -> Result<(), error::EncodeError>;
}

impl<W: Write> Encoder for W {
    fn write_u8(&mut self, value: u8) -> Result<(), error::EncodeError> {
        self.write(slice::from_ref(&value)).unwrap();
        Ok(())
    }

    fn write_var_int(&mut self, mut value: i32) -> Result<(), error::EncodeError> {
        loop {
            let mut byte = (value & 0b01111111) as u8;
    
            if byte == 0 {
                self.write_u8(byte).unwrap();
                break;
            }
    
            self.write_u8(byte | 0b10000000).unwrap();
            value = value >> 7;
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let test = [0; 17];
    let mut wrt = Cursor::new(test);
    wrt.write_var_int(3);
}
```

This produces the error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0599]: the method `write_var_int` exists for struct `std::io::Cursor<[{integer}; 17]>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:39:9
   |
39 |       wrt.write_var_int(3);
   |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `std::io::Cursor<[{integer}; 17]>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied because of the requirements of the implementation of `Encoder` for `_`:
      `std::io::Cursor<[{integer}; 17]>: std::io::Write`
  --> src/main.rs:14:16
   |
14 | impl<W: Write> Encoder for W {
   |                ^^^^^^^     ^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

The problem here is that we've got a `Cursor<[{integer}; 17]>`, but `Write` is [only implemented for a `Cursor<&mut [u8]>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html#impl-Write), where `&mut [u8]` is a mutable reference to a `u8` slice.

This makes sense if you think about it: `Cursor` wraps an in-memory buffer, but there's no need for it to take ownership of it.

So let's make sure we're passing a mutable slice to our `Cursor`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut test = [0u8; 17];
    let mut wrt = Cursor::new(&mut test[..]);
    wrt.write_var_int(3);
}
```

[This compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d5ce09732b099d1c639a4f7d314de734) as expected.